# Image quality is bad after saving using Glide Library

Tags: android, save, android-glide, image-quality

hi i'm trying to save picture downloaded in device storage i have this methods for save pictures in storage but after saved i find that the picture quality is bad please help me i want to save the picture with the same orignal quality

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load("YOUR_URL")
     .asBitmap()
     .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
               saveImage(resource);
          }});


 private String saveImage(Bitmap image) {
    String savedImagePath = null;

    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "FILE_NAME" + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = new File(
           Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    + "/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
        savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add the image to the system gallery
        galleryAddPic(savedImagePath);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "IMAGE SAVED"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return savedImagePath;
}

private void galleryAddPic(String imagePath) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(imagePath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: try using `.dontTransform()`.  Reference https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1227

Comment: @wick.ed doesn't work :(

Comment: aww :( `.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100)` could this be the issue?Increase it and see if it helps.  make it 600,600 or more to test. Also, try changing `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` to PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100)
```

Literally means that you want the image with a width of 100px and height of 100px, which is really really small, and i'm 99.99% sure this is what you mean with "bad quality".

If you want the 100% original image, you should use this:

```
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
```

"Target" is a class within Glide, and it has the "SIZE_ORIGINAL" constant.

That'll give you the full image, in original quality, which you can then save.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bitmap.compress is already in the max quality, you can change the format to PNG, but you´ll have no compress for the image, because PNG is a lossless format.

You can change the dimens of your image too, change `SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100)` to the original one.